# Renew free provisioning profile from CLI

Tags: ios, command-line, xcode, developer-program

I'm developing an iOS app to run only on my phone (a.k.a. sideloading), and I don't need to distribute it.  With a free iOS dev account, my provisioning profile expires every 7 days.  I'm looking for a way to automate the process of re-signing the app without launching Xcode.  So far my script is like this:

```
open myproject.xcodeproj
xcodebuild -project myproject.xcodeproj
osascript -e 'quit app "Xcode"'
ios-deploy --justlaunch --bundle ./build/Release-iphoneos/myproject.app
```

Simply opening Xcode GUI for a few seconds is enough to renew the provisioning profile.  But I'd like to do this all through the command-line.